# Send email to a friend is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, debug, send-mail

I am working with Magento 1.9.2 and send email to a friend is not sending emails. It gives sent successfully report message. But not sending. Any clue how to debug?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Got to System Transaction mail and load **Send Product to Friend** and check it loaded or not

[image]

then go to **System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Email to a Friend** and check below configuration is fine or not

[image]

then check if not working share me your **error.log**

Comment: in the log i found : 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message '5.7.1 <ideachanges@gmail.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user bineesh@sysbrick.com       |  the registered mail on system is bineesh@sysbrick.com . But the user may input any email , right ? so how to solve it. ?

Comment: Transaction mail is loading

Comment: contacts are going.

Comment: but i can send using bineesh@sysbrick.com

Comment: What is the problem give me your site url

Comment: this is my site https://mercande.com

Comment: I guess it's sever side problem please check with sever http://serverfault.com/questions/637726/sender-address-rejected-not-owned-by-user-in-postfix

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48774/discussion-between-bineesh-and-kothari).

Answer (score 0):

Check you've got postfix installed and make sure you've configured it. Otherwise check IPTables to ensure you've not got an outbound drop rule that's not allowing if out.

Check IPTables  with `iptables -L` if that has no rules then please share with me your post fix configuration.

Also check the service via `service postfix status`